# Trying to do a DEX CPI to perform fully on-chain swaps

Tags: cpi, swap, dex

I want to create a fully-onchain swap through any clmm dex so for this example I'm trying through raydium even tho I just want to make it work.

I'm using the github repo here to import necessary things : https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-clmm/blob/e6dd1d5673995d5c0de32862438f36b9af935e7c/programs/amm/src/instructions/swap_v2.rs

Here is my code:

```
#[program]
pub mod testraydium {
    use super::*;
  pub fn call_swap_v2(ctx: Context<SwapSingleV2>, amount: u64, other_amount_threshold: u64, sqrt_price_limit_x64: u128, 
        is_base_input: bool, cpi_program: Context<DoCpi>) -> anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult {
        // Call the swap_v2 function in the other crate
        //let cpi_program = cpi_program.accounts.other_program.clone();
        let callee_id = cpi_program.accounts.callee.clone();
        let cpi_accounts = SwapSingleV2 {
            payer: ctx.accounts.payer.clone(),
            amm_config: ctx.accounts.amm_config.clone(),
            pool_state: ctx.accounts.pool_state.clone(),
            input_token_account: ctx.accounts.input_token_account.clone(),
            output_token_account: ctx.accounts.output_token_account.clone(),
            input_vault: ctx.accounts.input_vault.clone(),
            output_vault: ctx.accounts.output_vault.clone(),
            observation_state: ctx.accounts.observation_state.clone(),
            token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.clone(),
            token_program_2022: ctx.accounts.token_program_2022.clone(),
            memo_program: ctx.accounts.memo_program.clone(),
            input_vault_mint: ctx.accounts.input_vault_mint.clone(),
            output_vault_mint: ctx.accounts.output_vault_mint.clone(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(callee_id, cpi_accounts);
        raydium_amm_v3::amm_v3::swap_v2(cpi_ctx, amount, other_amount_threshold, sqrt_price_limit_x64, is_base_input)
    }
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DoCpi<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub data_acc: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub raydium_amm_v3_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub callee: Program<'info, AmmV3>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SwapSingleV2<'info> {
    /// The user performing the swap
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// The factory state to read protocol fees
    #[account(address = pool_state.load()?.amm_config)]
    pub amm_config: Box<Account<'info, AmmConfig>>,

    /// The program account of the pool in which the swap will be performed
    #[account(mut)]
    pub pool_state: AccountLoader<'info, PoolState>,

    /// The user token account for input token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub input_token_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The user token account for output token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub output_token_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The vault token account for input token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub input_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The vault token account for output token
    #[account(mut)]
    pub output_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// The program account for the most recent oracle observation
    #[account(mut, address = pool_state.load()?.observation_key)]
    pub observation_state: AccountLoader<'info, ObservationState>,

    /// SPL program for token transfers
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    /// SPL program 2022 for token transfers
    pub token_program_2022: Program<'info, Token2022>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(
        address = spl_memo::id()
    )]
    pub memo_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// The mint of token vault 0
    #[account(
        address = input_vault.mint
    )]
    pub input_vault_mint: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,

    /// The mint of token vault 1
    #[account(
        address = output_vault.mint
    )]
    pub output_vault_mint: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,
    // remaining accounts
    // tickarray_bitmap_extension: must add account if need regardless the sequence
    // tick_array_account_1
    // tick_array_account_2
    // tick_array_account_...
}
```

So, after I will create a pub fn for another function and in this function it will do some things and at the end of this other function it would call_swap_v2 with necessary args to perform the swap.

But for now with this I got a lot of errors like:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `anchor_lang::context::Context<'static, 'static, 'static, 'static, DoCpi<'static>>: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
  --> programs/testraydium/src/lib.rs:21:1
   |
21 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `anchor_lang::context::Context<'static, 'static, 'static, 'static, DoCpi<'static>>`

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifiers
  --> programs/testraydium/src/lib.rs:21:1
   |
21 | #[program]
   | ^ expected 4 lifetime parameters
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
21 ~ #'a, 'a, 'a, 'a, [program]
22 | pub mod testraydium {
 ...
39 | */    
40 ~     pub fn call_swap_v2<'a>(ctx: Context<SwapSingleV2>, amount: u64, other_amount_threshold: u64, sqrt_price_limit_x64: u128,
```

So I'm blocked for now. Coming from ETH its a little hard for me to implement this (which is super easy on evm) so if you have any help like with another dex (but using clmm because I want to use token2022) with or without anchor I would be grateful

Comment: Learn rust first, lifetime is a pain when getting started.

Comment: I know rust but its a serialisation deserialisation problem here and I don’t think I should add a lifetime to program attribute